# toFixed is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm getting an error with my code, never got this before and is really weird.
I did try parseFloat but that didn't work either..
Code: https://gist.github.com/markd69/aca03cab20e46e0abae7d4f1e402092d

```
You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a 
Promise rejection:
TypeError: (((0.044000000000000004 * args[0]) + 0.3) + args[0]).toFixed is 
not a 
function
at Object.exports.run (/root/athex/athex-bot/commands/pay.js:12:54)
at Client.bot.on (/root/athex/athex-bot/index.js:316:11)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
at MessageCreateHandler.handler
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to accomplish and add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: did you try `Number(args[0])` ? I think you are getting `NaN.toFixed()`

Comment: That there's no `toFixed` means that `args[0]` is a string, or was coerced to. @MrAleister NaN is a number, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all to do with `args[0]` having the value of a `String`.

With `args[0]` as a string:

- `(0.044000000000000004 * args[0]) + 0.3)` results in a `Number`.
- `((0.044000000000000004 * args[0]) + 0.3) + args[0]` results in a `String`.

`.toFixed` is only found on `Number` objects, so this results in the `... is not a function` error.

---

Converting `args[0]` to a `Number` and using that will rectify the issue:

```
var num = Number(args[0]);
return (((0.044000000000000004 * num) + 0.3) + num).toFixed();
```

Comment: You can also use parseInt(math here)